# Closing child window when exiting main

Tags: pyqt5

I'm sure, it's a very basic thing but I just can't find out why closing the main window doesn't close the child

```
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv) #Main Window

Main = uic.loadUi("main.ui")
Child = uic.loadUi("child.ui")

def child():
    Child.show()

Main.button.pressed.connect(child)
Main.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

> void QWidget::setParent(QWidget *parent)
>
> Sets the parent of the widget to parent, and resets the window flags.

---

> QWidget::setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowFlags type)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


app = QApplication(sys.argv)      #Main Window

Main = uic.loadUi("main.ui")

Child = uic.loadUi("child.ui")

Child.setParent(Main)             # +++
Child.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window)   # +++


def child():
    Child.show()

Main.button.pressed.connect(child)

Main.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! This is it!

Comment: @jtamasi  If my answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, 
if you do not know how to do it then check the https://stackoverflow.com/tour